# How to add image quantity functions in printing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, printing

This is an example of what I want to achieve first the user will select the image and then they will input number of image pieces they want to show on the print page, I already created the functions of adding the image and printing it but it is only one I want to create like this one that can print multiple images depends on what user input.

This is my code:

```
var myApp = new function() {
this.geltint = function() {
var tab = document.getElementById('geltint');

var style = "<style>";
style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
style = style + "</style>";

var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
win.document.write(style); //  add the style.
win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
win.document.close();
win.print();
}
}
var myApp2 = new function() {
this.powdery = function() {
var tab = document.getElementById('powdery');

var style = "<style>";
style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
style = style + "</style>";

var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
win.document.write(style); //  add the style.
win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
win.document.close();
win.print();
}
}
var myApp3 = new function() {
this.powdery5ml = function() {
var tab = document.getElementById('powdery5ml');

var style = "<style>";
style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
style = style + "</style>";

var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
win.document.write(style); //  add the style.
win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
win.document.close();
win.print();
}
}

function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  $('#geltint')
    .attr('src', e.target.result)
    .width(244.8)
    .height(187.2);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

function readURL2(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader2 = new FileReader();

reader2.onload = function(e) {
  $('#powdery')
    .attr('src', e.target.result)
    .width(172.8)
    .height(230.4);
};

reader2.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

function readURL3(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader2 = new FileReader();

reader2.onload = function(e) {
  $('#powdery5ml')
    .attr('src', e.target.result)
    .width(244.8)
    .height(105.6);
};

reader2.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
group,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="1stimage">
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="geltint" src="#" alt="your image" />
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Print Table" onclick="myApp.geltint()" />
</p>
</div>

<div id="2ndimage">
<input type='file' onchange="readURL2(this);" />
<img id="powdery" src="#" alt="your image" />
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Print Table" onclick="myApp2.powdery()" />
</p>
</div>

<div id="3rdimage">
<input type='file' onchange="readURL3(this);" />
<img id="powdery5ml" src="#" alt="your image" />
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Print Table" onclick="myApp3.powdery5ml()" />
</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is EXAMPLE what I want my output to look plain and simple any suggestions or ideas you can share with me guys thank you so much.

Users will choose an image and then input quantity on how many copies of an image they want then press print And It will show the print preview like this with total numbers of images what the user input

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-loop` and iterate until  `<= quantity` where quantity is enter by user and inside this `for-loop` append `tab.outerHTML` in some variable using `+=` .So , you can change your code like below :

***HTML*** :

```
<div id="1stimage">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <!--added qty -->
  <input type="number" value="1" class="qty">
  <img id="geltint" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <p>
    <!--pass this as well-->
    <input type="button" value="Print Table" onclick="myApp.geltint(this)" />
  </p>
</div>
<!--do same for others ...->
```

***Js Code*** :

```
var myApp = new function() {
  this.geltint = function(el) {
    var tab = document.getElementById('geltint');
    var qty = $(el).closest("div").find(".qty").val(); //get qty value
    console.log(qty)
    var style = "<style>";
    style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
    style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
    style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
    style = style + "</style>";
    var html = "";
    //loop
    for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
      html += tab.outerHTML //append
    }

    var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
    win.document.write(style); //  add the style.
    win.document.write(html); //pass same
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: it all works good I achieve what does I want output you really help me a lot in this one I owe one Sir Thank you so much for the tutorial Keepsafe always sir. Thanks.

Comment: Maam may I ask if I am going to add spaces in each images in printing where should I add code?

Comment: You can change `html +="<div style='padding:10px'>"+tab.outerHTML+"</div>"` give any style there to make space between images.

Comment: Okay I get the idea Mam, one last question ma'am by the method you gave is it possible that I can print all three images and adding the count of quantity I input in just one click? I mean I will add "Print All" button so it will print all 3 images and there total quantity

Comment: Yes you can you need some kind of loop to iterate through your input  and get values of images then append it to some variable one by one . Try it at your end let me know if still that didn't work.

Comment: Maam I tried to reconstruct your code by merging the three javascript functions and insert "for loop" in each then reconstruct also the variable by creating new functions and calling all image ID at once but I am stock at blank printing there is no image showing, can you please help me with this one. :(

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2d9qsgyk/1/) fiddle will work for you.